# Why don't I get a heatmap graph with my code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to create a heatmap with the giving values. But after playing, it gives me one Rectangels. Normally, the whole graph must be filled with different coloured rectangles. What is wrong in my code? I have already tried many things. But unfortunately I don't know what to do and I am already despairing.

In this picture you can see what my edition looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <p>First Tutorial</p>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <div id="container"> </id>
  <script>

    /* JavaScript */
    var data = [
      [2.56, 8.52, 4.92, 2.58, 8.44, 2.29],
      [7.94, 8.42, 7.71, 7.0, 8.13, 5.63],
      [1.38, 3.29, 2.38, 2.85, 1.38, 1.77],
      [1.31, 2.48, 1.04, 1.21, 1.83, 1.48],
      [1.58, 8.19, 4.75, 3.38, 4.83, 1.46],
      [4.48, 4.08, 4.13, 1.73, 1.37, 2.58], ];

    var rowLabels = [
      "rowOne",
      "rowTwo",
      "rowThree",
      "rowFour",
      "rowFive",
      "rowSix",
    ];
    var columnLabels = [
      "columnOne",
      "columnTwo",
      "columnThree",
      "columnFour",
      "columnFive",
      "columnSix",
    ];

    const mapData = data.reduce((res, item, index) => {
      const group = rowLabels[index];
      item.forEach((value, colIndex) => {
        res.min = Math.min(value, res.min);
        res.max = Math.max(value, res.max);
        res.data.push({group, variable: columnLabels[colIndex], value});
      });
      return res;
    }, {data: [], min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY});

    /* Layout constants */
    var margin = {top: 0, right:0, bottom: 90, left: 80},
      width = 960- margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    /* Initialization of SVG graphics */
    var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //X Scale and Axis:
      var x= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ 0, width ])
      .domain(columnLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10) rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font-size", 10)
    
    // Y scales and Axis:
    var y= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ height, 0 ])
      .domain(rowLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

      var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#0000ff", "#00ff00"])
  .domain([mapData.min,mapData.max])

  svg.selectAll()
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
```

with:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.group) })
```

```js
    /* JavaScript */
    var data = [
      [2.56, 8.52, 4.92, 2.58, 8.44, 2.29],
      [7.94, 8.42, 7.71, 7.0, 8.13, 5.63],
      [1.38, 3.29, 2.38, 2.85, 1.38, 1.77],
      [1.31, 2.48, 1.04, 1.21, 1.83, 1.48],
      [1.58, 8.19, 4.75, 3.38, 4.83, 1.46],
      [4.48, 4.08, 4.13, 1.73, 1.37, 2.58]];

    var rowLabels = [
      "rowOne",
      "rowTwo",
      "rowThree",
      "rowFour",
      "rowFive",
      "rowSix",
    ];
    var columnLabels = [
      "columnOne",
      "columnTwo",
      "columnThree",
      "columnFour",
      "columnFive",
      "columnSix",
    ];

    const mapData = data.reduce((res, item, index) => {
      const group = rowLabels[index];
      item.forEach((value, colIndex) => {
        res.min = Math.min(value, res.min);
        res.max = Math.max(value, res.max);
        res.data.push({group, variable: columnLabels[colIndex], value});
      });
      return res;
    }, {data: [], min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY});

    /* Layout constants */
    var margin = {top: 0, right:0, bottom: 90, left: 80},
      width = 960- margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    /* Initialization of SVG graphics */
    var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //X Scale and Axis:
      var x= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ 0, width ])
      .domain(columnLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10) rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font-size", 10)
    
    // Y scales and Axis:
    var y= d3.scaleBand()
      .range([ height, 0 ])
      .domain(rowLabels)
      .padding(0.01);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

      var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#0000ff", "#00ff00"])
  .domain([mapData.min,mapData.max])

  console.log(mapData);
  //console.log()
  svg.selectAll()
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.group) })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <div id="container">
```